# How do I get access to xor64#

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do some programming with unboxed, 64 bit words. Specifically, I'd like to xor values of type `Word64#`. In the GHC.Word module I can see that the primitive operation `xor64#` is used for this purpose. But I cannot seem to get access to that operation. I tried to use the exact same import as the GHC.Word module but GHC still gives me an error saying that `xor64#` is not in scope. What should I import to get access to it?

Comment: Are you using a version of GHC that is not 64-bits? The `CPP` at the top of the `GHC.IntWord64` module (from `ghc-prim`) in which `xor64#` is defined makes it clear that these functions are only available if `WORD_SIZE_IN_BITS < 64`...

Comment: Is there some particular reason you can't just use the regular Data.Bits API on Word64? GHC is quite good at inlining and unboxing numeric code

Comment: @jberryman, GHC is indeed pretty good at optimizing boxed code into unboxed. The thing I'm trying to do here is test GHCs abilities. I already have a version of the code using the Data.Bits API and I want to compare the generated code to a version written using unboxed primitives.

Comment: Okay, as you probably know you can pretty easily see whether these optimizations kick in by looking at core (look for Int#, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ghc-prim`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim) package offers access to these low-level primitives.

On 64-bit (and higher) machines, `xor64#` is not used in `GHC.Word` (and not available from anywhere): it is `#if`'d out. Instead `xor#` is used, which is available from [`GHC.Prim`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.5.3/docs/GHC-Prim.html).

On lesser machines, `xor64#` is used and made available from `GHC.IntWord64`.

Comment: @Alec Are you sure? It isn't here, and from the source, `GHC.Word` doesn't even appear to import `GHC.IntWord64` on modern architectures.

Comment: @Alec Ah, I see what's going on. Okay, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yeah. I noticed and commented on the initial q too. `GHC.IntWord64` exports nothing unless `WORD_SIZE_IN_BITS < 64`.

Comment: Thanks. I get the feeling that the primops for Word64# are not exported on 64 bit machines and that I'm expected to just use Word#. If I'm right I think that's an unfortunate choice by the GHC developers since my code will compile just fine on a 32 bit machine but produce the wrong answer. Oh well, I guess I'll just have to write something about it in the documentation.

Comment: @svenningsson You can do what GHC does: use #if to differentiate.

Comment: @DanielWagner indeed I can do that. Though if the primitives for Word64# had been exported, I wouldn't have had to.

Comment: @svenningsson Yes, you would have still had to: there ain't no Word64# on 64-bit machines!

Comment: @DanielWagner, Word64# does actually exist on 64-bit machines. Try the following: id64 :: Word64# -> Word64#; id64 x = x. It compiles just fine. Too bad I can't do anything with values of the type...